# Python 3.6 кросплатформенная компиляция файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал на ОС Windows python-скрипт, мне его надо скомпилировать, чтобы можно было спокойно запустить на ОС Debian 8 (без установки нужных python-модулей). Можно ли это сделать с помощью cx_freeze, если нет то как?

Comment: Есть Си зависимости? какие? Вы уверены что хотите кросс-компиляцией Си библиотек на Windows для Debian заниматься? Подробней опишите ваш случай: на две строчки скрипт или больше, на кого рассчитан (найдёт пользователь терминал?), нужно ли обновлять? Как критична безопасность? Одноразовое мероприятие для одной Debian машины или больше?